Is there a way to create Apigee apps in Terraform or using APIs?
We create Apigee apps from the UI but it gets tedious when creating different apps for the same component. For example, if there's a component called 'DemoApp', I would create 3 apps such as 'dev_demoapp', 'test_demoapp' and 'preprod_demoapp'. Then these 3 apps would have the same parameters. Developer name (with email ID), 2 products (all_proxies, oauth_api_v1) with 'Approved' status and custom attribute (name='SrcApplicationId', value='DemoApp').
The number of apps would increase if I need to do it in more environments. I want to be able to do that in Terraform using one module for each component (if possible). For example, module 'demoapp' will have the 3 app names and all the parameters. I couldn't find anything in Terraform Registry.
If there is no such thing in Terraform, are there any APIs to do that?
I found this unofficial apigeetool on Github. It does say how to create apps using SDK or something. I have no clue about Node.js. Installed npm but unsure how to proceed from there.

I do not have any experience with Terraform, but do note that there are management APIs available to create developer apps on Apigee.
On doing a quick search I found Terraform REST API calls with cURL on Stackoverflow. May be this could give you some ideas on how to implement your use case.
